# Creating multiple zip files with assembly plugin - no assembly descriptors found

Tags: maven, plugins, maven-assembly-plugin

In addition to creating a war file in my pom (which works fine) I'm trying to create a couple of ZIP files that include only some of my content. Previously I had just one zip file and created my own assembly descriptor using the zip format, and this worked fine. When I wanted to add a second zip file with different content, I had to change my plugin to multiple executions. Now when I run it I get an error message that says no assembly descriptors found and that the build failed.

What's funny is that it actually is doing everything it needs to do. It creates the war file. It creates the two zip files, even though it says it failed to do so. But this maven build is one of many run by an automated deployment process, and if it gets an error message, that's not going to fly.

This is the plugin section of my pom:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.6</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>zip-metricsscnapshot</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/resources</outputDirectory>
            <finalName>metricssnapshot</finalName>
            <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>zip-metricdetails</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/resources</outputDirectory>
            <finalName>metricdetails</finalName>
            <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/details-zip.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

---

#### Solved

addendum:

I run maven with **clean yuicompressor:compress assembly:assembly package**.

My src/main/assembly directory contains two files, zip.xml and details-zip.xml. They are mostly identical except for the  element and the filesets. Here's the **zip.xml** file:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>widget</id>
    <baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <directory>src/main/webapp/resources/metricssnapshotwidget</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/metricssnapshotwidget.js</exclude>
                <exclude>**/metricssnapshotwidget.css</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Can you post the command you are using to launch Maven? Also, could you post the structure of the folder `src/main/assembly`?

Comment: mvn clean yuicompressor:compress assembly:assembly package

Comment: That is the issue then. Just run `mvn clean yuicompressor:compress package`

Comment: That did it! Build Success.

Comment: BTW: Bad idea to set outputDirectory to something which is located in the `src/.*`